# Using a loop to set the buttons onclicklistener

Tags: android, button, onclick, onclicklistener

I am trying to use a loop to set the action for each button when clicked (since most of the buttons will just return their text value), however I am getting an error stating "variable 'i' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final". How can I get around this?

Here is what I got

```
String getValuesPressed(){

    for(int i = 0; i < buttonList.length; i++){

        buttonList[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(i == 0){//error occurs here
                    //do stuff
                }

            }
        });
    }
    return textOnScreen;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can copy the value of `i` in to a temp final variable as -

```
for (int i = 0; i < buttonList.length; i++) {
        final int finalI = i;
        buttonList[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (finalI == 0) {//error occurs here
                    //do stuff
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) (`View.OnClickListener`) for each button, the `onClick()` method within that class has a different scope than the method `getValuesPressed()`, therefore it has no access to local variable `i`.

The solution is contained within the link provided above:

> An anonymous class cannot access local variables in its enclosing
>   scope that are not declared as final or effectively final.

Therefore introducing a final variable into the loop would resolve the error:

```
String getValuesPressed(){

    for(int i = 0; i < buttonList.length; i++){
        final int j = i;
        buttonList[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(j == 0){//error occurs here
                    //do stuff 
                } 

            } 
        }); 
    } 
    return textOnScreen; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create you own listener that takes the position as a parameter to workaround the fact you are using an anonymous inner class.

```
private class MyClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    int position;

    public MyClickListener (int position) {
        this.position = position;
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(position == 0){
            //do stuff 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Then in your loop you can create it like this

```
String getValuesPressed(){

    for(int i = 0; i < buttonList.length; i++){
        buttonList[i].setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(i)); 
    } 

    return textOnScreen; 
}
```