# how to create buttons with almost same work

Tags: android

I'm trying to create some buttons (number buttons {0, 1, ..., 9})
the way I did that, is this:

```
 button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(getNumber.getText().toString().length()>=2)
                return;
            getNumber.setText(getNumber.getText().toString() + "1");
        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(getNumber.getText().toString().length()>=2)
                return;
            getNumber.setText(getNumber.getText().toString() + "2");
        }
    });

    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(getNumber.getText().toString().length()>=2)
                return;
            getNumber.setText(getNumber.getText().toString() + "3");
        }
    });

    and so on ...
```

is there any better way to do this and prevent of writing the same things ?

Comment: check this thread  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31891481/using-a-loop-to-set-the-buttons-onclicklistener

Answer (score 3):

You can make your code cleaner by doing:

```
 button1.setOnClickListener(this);
 button2.setOnClickListener(this);
 button3.setOnClickListener(this);
 button4.setOnClickListener(this);
 button5.setOnClickListener(this);
 //..
```

.

Now:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
    {
       case button1:
           doSomeTask(getNumber.getText().toString(), "1");
           break;
       case button2:
           doSomeTask(getNumber.getText().toString(), "2");
           break;
       //...
    }
}
```

Now the `doSomeTask()`:

```
private void doSomeTask(String text, String num) {
    if(text.length()>=2)
       return;
    getNumber.setText(text + num);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have the following method:

```
private void setupButton(int btnId, int num) {
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(btnId)
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(getNumber.getText().toString().length() >= num) 
                return; 
            getNumber.setText(getNumber.getText().toString() + num); 
        } 
    }); 
}
```

We pass the button resource ID and the corresponding number to this method for each button.

Answer (score 1):

set tag to every button like `button1.Tag = 1;` `button2.Tag = 2;` and so on. and if in layout `android:tag="1"` for every button.

from @oneStepBack

```
 button1.setOnClickListener(this);
 button2.setOnClickListener(this);
 button3.setOnClickListener(this);
 button4.setOnClickListener(this);
 button5.setOnClickListener(this);
 //..
```

**Activity Code:**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
  doSomeTask(getNumber.getText().toString(), v.getTag());
}
```

**doSomeTask** from oneStepBack

```
private void doSomeTask(String text, String num) {
    if(text.length()>=2)
       return;
    getNumber.setText(text + num);
}
```

That's the practice that i follow for multiple button with same feature!